# "Standard" approach to collecting data from/distributing data to multiple devices/servers?

Tags: database, network-programming, synchronization, distributed, theory

I'll start with the scenario I am most interested in:

We have multiple devices (2 - 10) which all need to know about
a growing set of data (thousands to hundreds of thousands of small chunks,
say 100 - 1000 bytes each).
Data can be generated on any device and we
want every device to be able to get all the data *(edit: ..**eventually**. devices are not connected and/or online all the time, but they synchronize now and then)* No data needs
to be deleted or modified.

There are of course a few naive approaches to handle this, but I think
they all have some major drawbacks. Naively sending everything I
have to everyone else will lead to poor performance with lots of old data
being sent again and again. Sending an inventory first and then letting
other devices request what they are missing won't do much good for small
data. So maybe having each device remember when and who they talked to
could be a worthwhile tradeoff? As long as the number of partners
is relatively small saving the date of our last sync does not use that much
space, but it should be easy to just send what has been added since then.

But that's all just conjecture.
This could be a very broad
topic and I am also interested in the problem as a whole: (Decentralized) version control probably does something similar
to what I want, as does a piece of
software syncing photos from a users smart phone, tablet and camera to an online
storage, and so on.
Somehow they're all different though, and there are many factors like data size, bandwith, consistency requirements, processing power or how many devices have aggregated new data between syncs, to keep in mind, so what is the theory about this?
Where do I have to look to find
papers and such about what works and what doesn't, or is each case just so much
different from all the others that there are no good all round solutions?

**Clarification**: I'm not looking for ready made software solutions/products. It's more like the question what search algorithm to use to find paths in a graph. Computer science books will probably tell you it depends on the features of the graph (directed? weighted? hypergraph? euclidian?) or whether you will eventually need every possible path or just a few. There are different algorithms for whatever you need. I also considered posting this question on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would investigate a messaging service that implements the AMQP standard such as [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [OpenAMQ](http://www.openamq.org/), each time a new chunk is emitted, it should be sent to the AMQP broker which will broadcast it to all devices queues. Then the message may be pushed to the consumers or pulled from the queue.

Comment: Sounds like there is a central server or that at least one server has to be online all the time. That is not what I need and I am not really looking for libraries or frameworks, I'm more interested in (general) algorthims.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) for data streaming from several producers to several consumers. Other possibility is [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). It depends on your specific needs

Comment: From the linked Kafka page: "streams of data efficiently and in real time". That's not what I need, I don't care about real time, and it's often not even possible (think no signal on a mobile device). But I have never heard of Kafka before, thanks!

Comment: @Higemaru, most probably you will need to use one of this technologies combined with your own solution. Of course "real time" in the cloud and web services world has a different meaning than the traditional concept of real time. Most people uses "real time" to mean "very fast" and "Very fast" under certain constraints.

Comment: Sure, but I am not aiming for anything even close to real time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Amazon Simple notification service to solve this problem?

You can create a topic for each group of device you want to keep in sync. Whenever there is an update in dataset, the device can publish to the topic which in turn will be pushed to all devices using SNS.

Comment: No, and it doesn't seem to be what I am looking for. It seems overkill and I was looking more for algorthims, not finished software/services.

Comment: There are many ways to sync your devices. I have told you one, which I'd argue is not an overkill. It's actually quite simple and efficient.

Alternatively, you can sync your devices using a gossip protocol. The devices will have to maintain a fingerprint (hash of current state of world according to them). Whenever there is a change in their view of world, they can gossip to push the changes to other devices. The message complexity is pretty high in this case.

Comment: Have you read the last paragraph of my question? I'm not looking for a product, I'm looking for algorithms. I don't know much about Amazon SNS but how would it help in synchronizing? Remember, it's not an option (nor my goal) to send every update to every device whenever they occur, but to exchange information in a way that in the end all devices have all information. If a device isn't reachable where does the (Amazon SNS) message go?

Comment: Yes, I did read the last paragraph. And I gave you two algorithm to sync your devices. One using gossip protocol and one using publisher subscriber messaging model. If your devices go offline, you can store the data in a persistent store instead. Your devices should then be able to fetch the latest updates from the data store to become in sync with state of the world.

Comment: How would they fetch the latest updates from the data store? There is no single correct/most up to date state of the world, there are multiple states which need to be merged into one. We seem to have different notions of what an algorithm is. Is Amazon SNS open-source? If not how could I take a look at the algorithms they use? Gossip protocol seems to come with a lot of redundant messages, which is what I want to avoid.